# Django JsonResponse parsing error in Android

Tags: java, android, python, django, python-3.x

This is the JSON response I am getting from the server :

```
{
   "0": {
   "pk": 41,
   "fields": {
       "heading": "Empty Lecture Slot",
       "notification": "There is a free lecture available right now for TE B on 2018-05-02 8:00-9:00",
       "date": "2018-04-25",
       "priority": 1,
           "has_read": false,
           "action": "/dashboard/set_substitute/91959"
       },
       "model": "Dashboard.specificnotification"
   }
}
```

Here is the Java code used for parsing this JSON object :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

This is the error I am getting in the catch block :

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for {"0": {"pk": 41, "fields": {"heading": "Empty Lecture Slot", "notification": "There is a free lecture available right now for TE B on 2018-05-02 8:00-9:00", "date": "2018-04-25", "priority": 1, "has_read": false, "action": "/dashboard/set_substitute/91959"}, "model": "Dashboard.specificnotification"}}
```

How do I parse this object in Android.

Comment: I think you have to implement a POJO class in Java that matches the JSON object

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but doesn't JSON arrays start like this?:

`[
   {
    }
]`

Also the "0" seems to be not required. It will be automatically ordered

EDIT: you can also check online if your json is valid. Just google Json formatter.

Comment: I checked it before posting the question. It is a valid JSON.